# d3.js voronoi with overlapping data points

Tags: javascript, d3.js, voronoi

I am mapping tens of thousands of circles to a d3.js chart, with varying radii. Here is a screenshot (of a subset of the data, which can be filtered):

[image]

There is an overlaying voronoi diagram which is used to display a custom pop-up (with a bit of detail) when a user rolls over each circle. The voronoi points ("positions") have a random number assigned as the decimal, to prevent the issue of overlapping exactly similar data points. Here is a screenshot with the voronoi overlap:

[image]

However, the pop-up tooltip only displays when mousing over some of the data points, and not others.

I am using d3.js, v2 (not v3), and the code is at https://github.com/shaunjacobsen/divvy_savestime, with my progress so far visible at http://sjacobsen.com/testing/2015/bubble-chart.html. (It's difficult to append the large json datasets in jsfiddle).

Do you have any advice or guidance for how to get the pop-up to appear over *each* circle on mouseover? I greatly appreciate it.

**Edit:** I should note that this is based on http://ta.virot.me.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/hubway/hubway-summary.html

Comment: It appears that the mouseover event is triggered as expected, it's just that there's an error being thrown for some of the nodes: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'route' of undefined`. It's complaining about the line `var busRouteID = busRoute["route"];`. Either there's a bug in the way you find `busRoute`, or some routes just don't exist in your data.

Comment: @meetamit I feel like a fool! I am currently in the process of re-writing that entire portion of the data because it was not an efficient way of finding the route. It works now (I still need to work on getting it to hover near the data point, not at the bottom). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you use the voronoi diagram to show the tooltip? A better approach is a weighted voronoi with equalized areas for the circles.

Comment: Is this possible in d3? (Thanks for your comment).

Comment: @latortue09:The distance is substracted from the radii in weighted voronoi.

Comment: @shaunjacobsen There is a feature request to [add weighted voronoi to d3](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/1893).